# Model a team of workers assigned a job

Tags: sql, database-schema

This is what I have so far. I find it a bit messy, especially the many to many relationship between team and cleaner. Can that be made in a different way or do I keep it like this?
[image]

Comment: Doesn't look messy to me, as long as it meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Don't your teams have names? Oh the anonymity!
Sorry. :)

The `cleaner_team` table - as it is now - only makes sense, if a cleaner can be in multiple teams *at the same time*.
If they are e.g. in team A this week, team B next week, you'd add the week number. Or a date range.

If they can't, and keeping a team history isn't relevant, a simple foreign key from cleaner to team would suffice.

IMHO it is rare that a junction table having only the two foreign keys and no further attributes is the right solution.

Comment: Although I get your points, I think I need the junction table. As you assumed the teams will probably change with each commission and will also be used to calculate the pay for the employees and keeping the history of the teams will help keep a history of those payments.

Comment: If the teams themselves exist only for a limited time, then the date range would belong there. Of course, if a team is defined as *the group of cleaners working on one commission*, you could get rid of the team table altogether and make the junction between cleaners and commissions.